# How to get subprocess output of wmic in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wmic

I am making a tool in c++ to get the UUID of a computer, however I need to get the subprocess output of wmic and set it as a variable.

wmic command I will use.

```
wmic csproduct get uuid
```

My question is how will I set the output of this subprocess to a variable?

I have managed to do it python, however Im not sure how to do it in c++.

Python code:

```
x = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get UUID')
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of tool is it?

Comment: It is a HWID lock, because software keys are easy to crack, and I wont have a large customer base.